# Steps to Install and run headless chrome browser on centos 6.5 using chrome driver

Tags: linux, automation, selenium-chromedriver, centos7

I need to install chrome browser on centos 6.5, Here i need to automate some web gui. I have installed chrome driver. Can anyone please provide the steps and download link of chrome-61 and how to install it. My operating system does not have any Gui. Kindly provide the commands.

I am using java selenium.

Thanks in advance

Comment: trying to do the same. Have you figured anything out?

Comment: ooh, found something: https://tecadmin.net/install-google-chrome-in-centos-rhel-and-fedora/

Answer (score 43):

Sadly, Google Chrome no longer supports 6.x. You need CentOS 7.x.

I used  Cent-OS 7.4.* and it worked fine.

These are the steps to follow:

- **Download chromedriver**: login to Linux machine and execute these commands:

  ```
  $ wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.40/chromedriver_linux64.zip
  $ unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
  $ chromedriver --version
  ChromeDriver 2.40.565383
  ```

Make sure you're always installing the latest version!

- **Download Chromebrowser**

  ```
  $ wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
  $ sudo yum install google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm

  $ google-chrome --version
  Google Chrome 67.0.3396.87

  $ yum install Xvfb

  $ ps -ef | grep Xvfb
  username 12988     1  0 Oct05 ?        00:00:02 Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1152x900x8

  $ yum install maven
  $ mvn -version
  Apache Maven 3.0.5 (Red Hat 3.0.5-17)
  ```

Comment: Why Xvfb? Shouldn't headless Chrome use some kind of internal framebuffer instead of relying on X11?

Comment: You don't need Centos 7 -- see my answer below -- Chrome works well headless on Centos 6.

Comment: **1.** it is giving error `command chromedriver` not found. **2.** How to set Xvfb screen?When I executed this command it didnt show me screen size but appeared like this `19882 19405  0 16:26 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto Xvfb`

Comment: I have this on centos7
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-70.0.3538.110-1.x86_64 (/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64)
           Requires: liberation-fonts

Comment: check this link http://dist.control.lth.se/public/CentOS-7/x86_64/google.x86_64/ for specific versions for google-chrome

Comment: note: works fine without installing Xvfb and maven

Answer (score 5):

This is the guide to install Google Chrome on CentOS 6. Big thanks to the guys at Intoli.com!

It also works for Amazon Linux and Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

https://intoli.com/blog/installing-google-chrome-on-centos/

Comment: you da real MVP

Comment: Two years on and I'm not sure this works any more.  Chrome flakes out with 

```
google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu https://google.com
[0105/235507.059608:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(378)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

or

```
google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer https://google.com
[0105/235527.967960:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(457)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is 

```

Answer (score 0):

Actually ,  There is a way  to  run  both chrome and chromedriver  on amazon linux, centos 6.x and rhel. basic idea  to  use libs from a newer os.

See the  fully  automated script here 
https://github.com/staier/chromedriver-centos6-installation

This one adds  chromedriver  installation to  the 
 script from  the  article:https://intoli.com/blog/installing-google-chrome-on-centos/