# Download file onto virtual server using python

Tags: python, virtual-machine

I use a python script to download a file from a website periodically. I want to move this process to my virtual server. How do I do this?

This is the code I use

```
import webbrowser
url = 'https://www.djppr.kemenkeu.go.id/page/loadViewer?idViewer=9369&action=download'
chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s' #Windows
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
```

Visiting the link results in the file being automatically downloaded onto my PC. The issue is that there is no "chrome browser" on my virtual server. I also don't know whether it will save the file as it does on my PC.

Comment: launch `wget` for this link?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download a file over HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-to-download-a-file-over-http)

Answer (score 0):

1. install [Chrome headless](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) on server ([Ubuntu](https://gist.github.com/ipepe/94389528e2263486e53645fa0e65578b), [CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46109812/steps-to-install-and-run-headless-chrome-browser-on-centos-6-5-using-chrome-driv))
2. use [python + selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920243/how-to-configure-chromedriver-to-initiate-chrome-browser-in-headless-mode-throug) to run chrome headless in background
3. profit

Or just use [`requests`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/download-large-file-in-python-with-requests) or [`urllib`](https://stackabuse.com/download-files-with-python) python libraries if you don't need javascript support on client side.

In other way you may use [PhatomJS](https://realpython.com/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/) instead of Chrome browser